# java split string[] array to multiple files

Tags: java, json, string, file

I'm having a problem figuring out how to split a string to multiple files. At the moment I should get two files both with JSON data. The code below writes to the first file but leaves the second empty. Any ideas why?

```
public void splitFile(List<String> results) throws IOException {

  int name = 0;
  for (int i=0; i<results.size(); i ++) {

    write = new FileWriter("/home/tom/files/"+ name +".json");
    out = new BufferedWriter(write);
    out.write(results.get(i));

    if (results.get(i).startsWith("}")) {
      name++;
    }      
  } 
}
```

Edit: it splits at line starting with `{` because that denotes the end of a JSON document.

Comment: Where are you closing the file with `close()`? If you are writing everything at once, you don't need BufferedWriter. Make `write` a local variable inside the loop.

Comment: The code is broken because it tries to re-open the same file across iterations. Also, close the stream when done. Move `write` out of the loop and in the `if` statement close the current and open the next file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Enhance the cut-control**

Get togher this:

```
write = new FileWriter("/home/tom/files/"+ name +".json");
out = new BufferedWriter(write);
```

and this:

```
name++;
```

**Check for starting, not for end**

Check for line starting with `{`, and execute those three lines to open the file.

**Remember to close and flush**

If it's not the first line (`i > 0`) then close the last writer  (`write.close();`).

**Close the last opened writer**

```
if (!results.isEmpty())
    out.close();
```

**Result**

It should look something like this:

```
public void splitFile(List<String> results) throws IOException {

  int name = 0;

  BufferedWriter out = null;
  for (int i=0; i<results.size(); i ++) {
    String line = results.get(i);
    if (line.startsWith("{")) {
       if (out != null) // it's not the first
          out.close(); // tell buffered it's going to close, it makes it flush
       FileWriter writer = new FileWriter("/home/tom/files/"+ name +".json");
       out = new BufferedWriter(writer);
       name++;
    }
    if (out == null)
       throw new IllegalArgumentException("first line doesn't start with {");
    out.write(line);
  } 

  if (out != null) // there was at least one file
     out.close();
}
```

Comment: This will fail if you get { in the first iteration. Not tried, but I bet it doesn't even compile ("`out` may not have been initialized").

Comment: This works perfectly with the test file I'm using. out and write and declared 'private static' in the class so they are initialized. Thanks =)

Comment: I think you wanted to say "will fail if you don't get { in the first iteration". Certainly. I'm not sure of compile errors. I wrote it here, not tried it. But is just an indication of how all the advises would look like. I'll correct the not been initialized.

Comment: Thanks @Schmooo . Please take into account the comments and modifications I've made from them (checking out != null, checking first like with "{", and so on)

Comment: One more thing. Initialized means "with an assigned value, even null". If you just declare the variable without the `= ...` part the warning/error is thrown at compilation time. Another very important thing: why do you need it private static? You just need it private to the method. If it's a field or static field it could be left initialized from a previous execution and checks (like `out != null`) will provoke incorrect behaviour.

Comment: Eclipse was complaining about them not being static when I had them as just `private`

Answer (score 1):

I would close your buffered writer after each completed write sequence. i.e. after each iteration through the loop before you assign `write` to a new `FileWriter()`.

Closing the `BufferedWriter` will close the underlying `FileWriter`, and *consequently force a flush on the data written to the disk*.

Note: If you're using a distinct `FileWriter` per loop then I'd scope that variable to that inner loop e.g.

```
FileWriter write = new FileWriter("/home/tom/files/"+ name +".json");
```

The same goes for the `BufferedWriter`. In fact you can write:

```
BufferedWriter outer = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(...
```

and just deal with `outer`.

Comment: The problem is Schmooo wants to write several lines (several loop iterations) into the same file. That's why there's a check at the end of the loop looking for outermost JSON object closing.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following code..

```
    public void splitFile(List<String> results) throws IOException {

    int name = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < results.size(); i++) {

        write = new FileWriter("/home/tom/files/" + name + ".json");
        out = new BufferedWriter(write);
        out.write(results.get(i));
        out.flush();
        out.close();  // you have to close your stream every time in your case.

        if (results.get(i).startsWith("}")) {
            name++;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This will trample over the contents of the file created in the previous iteration.

Comment: I think results are lines and some lines go together in the same file (that's why name increments only when `}` is found).

Comment: This does trample the contents, anyway to get around this? Would it be better to use a StringBuilder then write the contents of that to a file?

Comment: Schmoo, it would help if you have `write` reassigned only each time after `name++`. Before reassignment you need to close the old file, of course.